# Action Filters to only load data for certain action types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, filter, action, onactionexecuting

I am relatively new to the MVC way of doing things and have run into a bit of a performance issue due to loading a lot of extraneous data in a base controller.  I have read a bit about action filters and was wondering if anyone had advice on how to proceed.  Here is my issue:

I have a Controller called RegController that inherits from a base Controller called BaseController.  In the onActionExectuting method of the base controller I load several variables, etc. that will be used in a visible page such as viewbag, viewdata, etc.  I only need to load this stuff for Actions with the result type ActionResult.  In the same RegController I also have some JsonResult Actions that do not need all of this extra info loaded because they do not load a page or view template they only return Json.  Does anyone have a suggestion how to handle this properly within existing framework features?  Should I be putting these action in different controllers instead?  I have many controllers with varying functionality split up in this same way and am hoping I can filter the action type versus moving them all to a JsonResultController or whatever.

Code (some of it pseudo) below:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected string RegId;

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("rid") && filterContext.ActionParameters["rid"] != null)
            RegId = filterContext.ActionParameters["rid"].ToString();

        Reg oReg = new Reg(RegId);

        // IF A VISIBLE PAGE IS BEING SERVED UP, I NEED TO LOAD THE VIEWDATA FOR THE PAGE
        SetViewAndMiscData(oReg);

        // IF THIS IS A JSON RESULT ACTION, I DO NOT WANT TO LOAD THE VIEWDATA FOR THE PAGE
    }
}

public class RegController : BaseController
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    public ActionResult Page(string id)
    {
        // THE VIEW DATA SHOULD BE SET FROM THE BASECONTROLLER FOR USE IN THE PAGE
        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult Save(string id, string data)
    {
        // I DON"T NEED ALL OF THE VIEW AND MISC DATA LOADED HERE, INCLUDING THE AUTO LOAD
        // OF THE REG OBJECT SINCE I DO IT HERE FROM THE PASSED PARAMS.

        GenericResponseObject Response = new GenericResponseObject();
        Reg oReg = new Reg(id);

        if (!oReg.IsValid)
        {
            Response.Status = 1;
            Response.Message = "Invalid Record";
        }
        else
            Response = oReg.SaveData(data);

        return Json(Response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Why not an action filter adorned on each action type?  One for actionresult and another for jsonresult?  What's the goal?  Reduce code with a base controller?  Sometimes this introduces more issues when you have to code for special circumstances in your base when just creating more controllers solves the issue and promotes the KISS principle.

Comment: @Stinky Towel: Yes that is what I am after I think, but I am unclear how exactly to set that up.  The base controller does far more than my example here, I just whittled it down for easy consumption. There are a myriad of things I load in the base and at least 4 different controllers have pages that need access to that data. I am also using it to eliminate redundant code.

Comment: Look at action filters instead of base controllers.  You can adorn a controller with the action filter which trickles down to all child actions or adorn the action specifically.  This way you can have a RegFilter or JsonFilter and adorn appropriately.  It also leaves u the flexibility to not adorn at all for actions that don't need special logic.  Having a few action filters should still meet your goal of limiting the number of places you have to make code chgs. See http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/b11a280114-Understanding-ASP.NET-MVC-Filters-and-Attributes.html

Comment: Thanks I will look at adding action filters.  I have made a test one and it seems to work. One question - can you combine base controllers with action filters?  For example let's say I have a single base controller that loads a single object that every single type of action across the app will need.  Can I do this in the base and then add filters to load the additional necessary stuff for the specific action types?